# Polyglossia difference between "\text<lang>{...}" and "\begin{<lang>} ... \end{<lang>}"

Tags: polyglossia

Beside the syntax, are there any other differences and use cases
when one should use `\text<lang>{...}` vs `\begin{<lang>} ... \end{<lang>}` to
select another language, i.e., insert snippets of text written in
another language?

The documentation only stipulates longer pieces
of text in favor for the environment syntax.

PS. It was my original understanding that the environment syntax
started a new line before inserting the text, but a quick test proved
me wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not the same. With `\text<language>{text}` you're doing `\foreignlanguage{<language>}{text}`, whereas `\begin{<language>}` is the same as `\begin{otherlanguage}{<language>}`

The environment form also changes the tags, which is not the case with the command form, as seen in the following example; dates are changed by both forms.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{italian}

\begin{document}

Nothing: \chaptername\ \today

\texttt{\string\textitalian}: \textitalian{\chaptername\ \today}

Environment:

\begin{italian}
\chaptername\ \today
\end{italian}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the `.aux` file you'll find

```
\select@language {english}
\select@language {italian}
\select@language {english}
```

(among other things); the first is written at the start, the second is caused by `\begin{italian}` and the third by `\end{italian}`. Usage of `\textitalian` won't make such an annotation.

Comment: It would be nice if an explanation such as this one made it into the next version of the `polyglossia` user guide.